# Как получить индекс из функции?

Tags: c#, функции

Есть вот такая функция:

```
static bool LogPassCheck(string input, string[] data_base)
        {
            int i;
            
            for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_USERS; i++)
            {
                if (input == data_base[i])
                {
                   //Как мне получить значение i в этом месте чтобы использовать его в Main

                     return true;
                    
                }


            }
            return false;
            
        }
```

Вопрос в коде.

Comment: `var index = Array.IndexOf(data_base, input);` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Классический вариант через out

```
static bool LogPassCheck(string input, string[] data_base, out int index)
{
    for (index = 0; index < 10; index++)
    {
        if (input == data_base[index])
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Вызов

```
  int index = -1;
  if(LogPassCheck("",data_base, out index ))
  {
  }
```

2.Через Tuple

```
static (bool flag, int index) LogPassCheck(string input, string[] data_base)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (input == data_base[i])
        {
            return (flag: true, index: i);
        }
    }
    return (flag: false, index: -1);
}
```